# Cannot allocate vector error despite allocating sufficient memory

Tags: bash, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, slurm

I want to run an R script on HPC and allocated 200GB memory. However, it still raises `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 868.4 Mb`.

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --mem=200g

module load R/4.2.2
Rscript remap.R
```

Traceback:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 868.4 Mb
Execution halted
```

Comment: How much memory are you expecting your code to use?
The obvious solution is to request more memory.

Comment: Also make sure, that the `SBATCH` line is taken into account by having a look at the output of the `scontrol show job JOBID` command where you replace `JOBID` with the actual job ID.